# Error when converting matrix to structure?

Tags: matlab

I am trying out the following in Matlab:
[Traveling Salesman Problem - Genetic Algorithm by Joseph Kirk](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13680-traveling-salesman-problem-genetic-algorithm)

However, when I create a matrix and try to pass it in a struct I get an error:

```
B = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8];
C = struct(B);
tsp_ga(C);
```

Error:

```
Error using struct
Conversion to struct from double is not possible.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The error is not thrown when you are calling the function, but when you try to create a struct with `struct(B)`. Use `C.A = B` or `C = struct('A',B)`, where A is the name of the field. You can change this name as you please.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved it!

Comment: You can type `help struct` in MATLAB to get help on using the `struct` function. `doc struct` will open the full documentation page.